# Замена двойных кавычек на одинарные

Tags: sed

Необходимо заменить " на ' в файле.

```
$ cat log.txt |sed 's/"/'/'
```

не работает

Comment: `sed s/\"/\'/g` попробуйте экранировать символы не беря шаблон замены в кавычки, так же `cat log` избыточный, можно просто `sed s/\"/\'/g log.txt`

Comment: `"s/\"/'/"` или `'s/"/'\''/'`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```
sed -i 's/"/'"'"'/g' log.txt     # GNU sed
sed -i '' 's/"/'"'"'/g' log.txt  # FreeBSD sed
```

Тут простое объединение строк: `'s/"/'` + `"'"` + `'/g'`. Обратите внимание на модификатор / флаг `g`, благодаря которому происходит поиск и замена *всех* совпадений на каждой строчке.

[Пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/qoKRfR):

```
log='"Война и мир"'
sed 's/"/'"'"'/g' <<< "$log"
## => 'Война и мир'
```

Comment: `sed -i -e ...` — универсально

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin  Универсально — это `ed(1)`, потому что в _POSIX_ `sed(1)` вообще не правит файлы _in-place_ :-)  Он называется «*stream editor*» неспроста.